# Next.js - Is there a way to add URL query params in a redirect?

Tags: redirect, next.js

In `next.config.js`, I'm attempting to redirect a shortened URL to the real URL with added query parameters, but when it redirects the query parameters aren't shown.

next.config.js

```
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/test',
        destination: '/testing-page?redirect=true',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
}
```

When I try `localhost:3000/test`, it just redirects me to `localhost:3000/testing-page` and not `localhost:3000/testing-page?redirect=true`.

Comment: What if you set `permanent` as `false`?

Comment: I am facing the same issues using version `14.0.3` trying to redirect from `/admin` to `/admin?search=term` in my next.config.js file. Tried setting `permanent` to `false` but still the URL does not get included with query params.

Answer (score 0):

Redirects defined in next.config.js takes the search parameters (parameters like ?redirect=something) and passes them to the redirect destination. If you need more fine control, you can implement it manually in getServerSideProps.

In this case, (assuming you are using pages router) try it like:

```
//test.jsx
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const target = "/testing-page?redirect=true"
    const statusCode = 308; // Change this to your desired type (302/307/308,...)
    context.res.writeHead(statusCode, { Location: target });
    context.res.end();
    return { props : {} };
}

export default function testing() {
    // some dummy function to export. This wont be called.
    console.log("Redirecting")
}
```